# Reverse & Time Ramping Effect Issue

Tags: premiere, slowmotion

What I'm trying to do is to show part of clip and then start reversing on it...

So i made a key frame and add a "speed remapping" effect, slow the video, then i duplicate that video, and everything to this point is fine... the video start normally, goes to the speed of zero, then slowly back to normal speed in reveres.

Now i want to do the reveres in higher speed, to the beginning of the video... so using trim tools, i extend the reversed video to the very beginning, and here's the buggy part:
I drag the "speed remapping" up, to speed it up, it get speeds, but the issue is, it adds from the begin of reversed clip not the end... and it cause my two clip to goes out of sync... it slows down in one frame, and start to speed up in a totally non related frame.

How to make it extend on the end point

Thank you.

---

### Edited

**Visual Explaination:**

Okey, Here's a normal timeline with some marker to show the effect...
So think about this, as our begin state:

[image: Normal Video Timeline with two speed change marker]

No i add another marker at the end, and start changing speed, as you can see the end of the clip got shorter, but our previous marker are same, it mean it fill the shortage from the end of the clip (cut from end)

[image: Normal Video Timeline with three speed change marker]

Now i undo to our begin state and reverse the video clip

[image: Reversing a Video Timeline]

You can see the begin state of reversed state

[image: Reversed Video Timeline with two speed change marker]

Now i add a marker at the end, same to what we did with the first video...
and start speeding up the video, as you can see this time our existing marker are moving, and it adds frame to the begin of clip not the end

[image: Reversed Video Timeline with three speed change marker]

Now here what i have, this little guys in here suppose to show a part of event which i important to me, then slow down to freeze, then reverse and maintain the speed, then goes to higher speed to the very beginning of the movie

[image: Normal Slow down and reverse video timeline]

But when i add/change the marker, instead of add/remove frames from the end of second clip, it take them from the start, and cause those two clip (specific frames) goes out of sync. it end at some place, and start at somewhere totally not related

[image: Buggy slow down and reverse video timeline with extra marker]

Comment: Kinda hard to understand what's going on here. A screenshot might help get you better answers.

Comment: @stib I added the screen shots

Comment: @stib so no one hold the answer? :'(... how to anchor to the first frame on timeline (which is last frame on actual reversed clip) and do time remapping, which increase or decrease the amount of loaded clip from the end?